# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils error

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml

I am facing a difficulty with my maven project. When I compile it in Eclipse, it works fine, but when I compile it through cmd and try to run it there, I get an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils. My POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.bootclasspath>C:\Program
            Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar${path.separator}C:\Program
            Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\jsse.jar${path.separator}C:\Program
            Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\jce.jar</maven.compiler.bootclasspath>
    </properties>

    <groupId>si.posta</groupId>
    <artifactId>espremnica</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>wsdltoJava</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlUrls>
                                <wsdlUrl>https://tsteportal.posta.si/Services/eSpremnica.Provider/WCF/eOddaja.svc?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                            </wsdlUrls>
                            <vmArgs>
                                <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                            </vmArgs>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                            <packageName>si.posta.espremnica.generated</packageName>
                            <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/java/generated</sourceDestDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>si.posta.espremnica.client.Client</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Can anyone suggest, where did I go wrong, or what did I not include here?

Comment: Just to be sure: you use maven on the command line, and your eclipse build uses the exact same project/setup definitions?

Comment: Hello, yes - correct.